# How to improve query efficiency

Tags: arangodb, aql

I have a problem I do not understand.For example, a cluster has three nodes,
each node is agent, coordinate, and dbserver, I execute an aql query on a node,The implementation plan is as follows:

Query string:

```
FOR v,p IN outbound
SHORTEST_PATH @startnode
TO @endnode
GRAPH @graphname options {bfs:true}
filter v.c_id==@c_id
return v
```

Execution plan:

```
Id NodeType Site Est. Comment
1 SingletonNode COOR 1 * ROOT
2 ShortestPathNode COOR 10000000 - FOR v /* vertex /, p / edge / IN OUTBOUND SHORTEST_PATH 'contact_vertex/f69375e854a34250986399d1909c0776' / startnode / TO 'contact_vertex/e11a10f848cd4a4392b8f10ea307eac9' / targetnode / GRAPH 'an'
3 CalculationNode COOR 10000000 - LET #4 = (v.c_id == -2147483643) / simple expression */
4 FilterNode COOR 10000000 - FILTER #4
5 ReturnNode COOR 10000000 - RETURN v
```

Indexes used:

```
none
```

Shortest paths on graphs:

```
Id Vertex collections Edge collections
2 contact_vertex contact_edge
```

Optimization rules applied:

```
none
```

I want to know if the querying task is distributed on one node or all nodes?In other words, the query is whether the task is distributed computing?
As in the above query,I have a lot of data,I have two collection, one vertexes collection and one edge collection,I use the default index,two collection constituted a graph,there is no way to quickly improve the search speed?For example, set the index, improve the query memory, and so on.Or some other suggestions, I hope you can help me.

My cluster starts as follows:

```
arangodb --starter.join 10.200.11.32,10.200.11.34,10.200.11.35
```

How should I set up my cluster?
I have three node configurations are the same：

```
RAM:254G    core:40
```